# Export in excel will not properly show data

Tags: python, csv, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I have to export some data to excel but I want it to export the lists into in columns based on their category( username, time, body, tags, inlink)

What am I missing here because I get everything in a row.

```
lists =[]
lists2=[]
lists3=[]
lists4=[]
lists5=[]
for i in range(0,33):
    link = (df.link.iloc[i])
    source1 = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read()
    soup1 = bs.BeautifulSoup(source1,'lxml')
    for username in soup1.find_all('div', class_="user-name"):
        lists.append([username.get_text().strip()])
    for time in soup1.find_all('div',class_="thread-ago"):
        lists2.append([time.get_text().strip()])
    for body in soup1.find_all('div',class_="thread-body"):
        lists3.append([body.get_text().strip()])
    for tags in soup1.find_all('div', class_="data-tag"):
        lists4.append([tags.get_text().strip()])
    for inlink in soup1.find_all('a',class_="thread-detail"):
        lists5.append([inlink.get('href')])

rows = zip(lists,lists2,lists3, lists4,lists5)        

example = open('generalinfo.csv','w')
for column in rows:
    wr = csv.writer(example,quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL,delimiter = ",")        
    wr.writerows(column)    
example.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
lists =[]
lists2=[]
lists3=[]
lists4=[]
lists5=[]
for i in range(0,33):
    link = (df.link.iloc[i])
    source1 = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read()
    soup1 = bs.BeautifulSoup(source1,'lxml')
    for username in soup1.find_all('div', class_="user-name"):
        lists.append([username.get_text().strip()])
    for time in soup1.find_all('div',class_="thread-ago"):
        lists2.append([time.get_text().strip()])
    for body in soup1.find_all('div',class_="thread-body"):
        lists3.append([body.get_text().strip()])
    for tags in soup1.find_all('div', class_="data-tag"):
        lists4.append([tags.get_text().strip()])
    for inlink in soup1.find_all('a',class_="thread-detail"):
        lists5.append([inlink.get('href')])

rows = zip(lists,lists2,lists3, lists4,lists5)  
with open('generalinfo.csv','w') as csvfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile,quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL,delimiter = ",")  
    for row in rows:              
        wr.writerows([row])
```